# what class replace physics factory in andengine?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have a small problem.
Last night i looking for a way to replace this class but I didn't found anything
In old version of andengine tutorial ,they used "PhysicsFactory.class"to create a fixtureDef.
In a recent example I seen something like that

```
FixtureDef ballShapeDef = new FixtureDef();
ballShapeDef.shape = circle;
ballShapeDef.density = 1.0f;
ballShapeDef.friction = 0.2f;
ballShapeDef.restitution = 0.8f;
ballBody.createFixture(ballShapeDef);
```

but i don"t know if physicsFactory and this code above mean the same thing with but a different way ,so now i'am a little bit confused .

someone can help ?

Comment: Me also confused.What you are actually looking for?

Comment: I asking me if fixtureDef with this parameter above mean and do the same things as when they used physicsFactor to create a boxbody?

Answer (score 0):

from the source code of the PhysicsFactory class:

```
public static FixtureDef createFixtureDef(final float pDensity, final float pElasticity, final float pFriction) {
    return PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(pDensity, pElasticity, pFriction, false);
}

public static FixtureDef createFixtureDef(final float pDensity, final float pElasticity, final float pFriction, final boolean pSensor) {
    final FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.density = pDensity;
    fixtureDef.restitution = pElasticity;
    fixtureDef.friction = pFriction;
    fixtureDef.isSensor = pSensor;
    return fixtureDef;
}

public static FixtureDef createFixtureDef(final float pDensity, final float pElasticity, final float pFriction, final boolean pSensor, final short pCategoryBits, final short pMaskBits, final short pGroupIndex) {
    final FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.density = pDensity;
    fixtureDef.restitution = pElasticity;
    fixtureDef.friction = pFriction;
    fixtureDef.isSensor = pSensor;
    final Filter filter = fixtureDef.filter;
    filter.categoryBits = pCategoryBits;
    filter.maskBits = pMaskBits;
    filter.groupIndex = pGroupIndex;
    return fixtureDef;
}
```

It looks like the same thing, but why don't you just use the PhysicsFactory?

Comment: You are right ,I don't know why don't do this before.thank you for your help I gonna do this and Merry Christmas